# DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader using different namespace for table relationships

Tags: database-schema, derived-class, dbix-class, perl

I want
[`DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader)
to create a class (say `OurSchemaBase::*`) for each of my tables.

Then I want to derive each of these classes and put them in, say, `OurSchema::*` and I want the relationship to point to my derived class not to the autogenerated base class.

Can I make `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader` create relationships in `OurSchemaBase::*` to `OurSchema::*` classes instead of to `OurSchemaBase::*` classes?

Is this possible with `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader`?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing related directly to Schema::Loader, check out https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Helper::Row::SubClass.